# Ordering of the PATH environment variable

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Locally here on Ubuntu 14.04, my `$PATH` looks something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

When I manually define the path for cron jobs or in Puppet/Ansible provisioning configuration, I usually flip the `PATH` environment variable around like this:

```
PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Is there a security best-practice for ordering the entries in the `PATH` environment variable? I'd assume that it'd be best to prefer entries in an `sbin` directory over entries in a `bin` directory. I've noticed that on certain RHEL boxes, the `PATH` omits `/sbin` by default.

That said, what would be a security best practice for the `PATH` environment variable for:

1. User Unix accounts.
2. Administrator Unix accounts.
3. Cron jobs/configuration management processes.

Answer (score 11):

If there's a directory in the search path where someone you don't trust could write files, then the directory should not be in the path, period.

The order only matters if a command is present in more than one entry in the list. So the only case to consider is when someone trustworthy arranged to have one entry shadowing another, deliberately or not.

If it was deliberate, then the order should be to search the directories in order of local management: typically this means first `~/bin` or equivalent if running under an account that has such a directory (not applicable to most system accounts), then `/usr/local/bin`, then the directories managed by the package manager `/usr/bin/` and `/bin`.

In principle, there should not be any shadowing between `sbin` and `bin` directories. `sbin` directories are for commands that are only useful to a system administrator (this is why these directories are normally not in the path of users other than root). In principle there could be a command name for which you want to run a different executable as root, so `sbin` directories should be ahead of the corresponding `bin` directory — otherwise `…/sbin/foo` would never be executed since it would be shadowed by `…/bin/foo` for everyone.

The only case when there is an ambiguity is if there may have been accidental shadowing. In that case there isn't an obvious answer. Generally, it doesn't make much sense to put `/usr/local/bin` after `/usr/bin`: if you don't want the local administrator's choice of commands, then don't put `/usr/local/bin` in the search path at all (and remove `/usr/local/lib` from the library search path, etc.).

Between `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, in principle, one might want to shadow an executable from `/bin` (small version for boot time only) with one from `/usr/bin` (large version from a separately-mounted `/usr` partition), but tiny root partitions with a separate `/usr` are a very uncommon practice these days. It was a more common practice in the days when operating systems used significant disk space, but even then shadowing utilities in `/bin` with versions from `/usr/bin` was uncommon. The other order, putting `/bin` first, has a slight performance benefit (`/bin` is usually a lot smaller). On most systems there's no strong reason to prefer one order over the other. (On some systems `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same directory, but you shouldn't assume that unless you only ever work on recent versions of one of the distributions that do this.)

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` (or `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`) is usually the right setting for jobs running as root, and `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` for jobs not running as root. I don't see any good reason to deviate from that (except for the `/usr` vs. `/` inversion) except to cater for local variations (e.g. a site-specific directory on *BSD distinct from the packages installed to `/usr/local`). Security-wise, it doesn't matter, but functionality-wise, putting `/usr/local` ahead of `/usr` and `/` is either indifferent or necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As this page is now the first or second search result for queries about Linux path precedence, path order, etc. it seems worth adding an explicit short answer:

**`PATH` order precedence is determined first to last, with earlier entries having priority.**

The earlier answer is correct that no entry with untrusted files (or write access to other users) should be in `PATH`. Unfortunately many development packages (`go`, `npm`, `pip`, etc.) include executable files which may need to be in PATH for integration or real-world usage.

That situation makes them good candidates for occurring later in the path as a best practice. Or conversely, if a custom executable that you require has the same name as a command you never use: with caution, you can put that earlier in the path.